# Is it possible to have a cubical type theory with pattern matching on the identity path?

Tags: cubical-type-theory, regularity

We have the lovely dependent pattern matching on `refl` constructor of identity type in systems like Agda, but the same feature is missing for Cubical Agda. People [want](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/3551) (well, at least Martin Escardo who created the ticket) to have this feature, and I'm thinking about how to do it.

In normal Agda, pattern matching on `refl` means two things:

0. It rewrites the current context with the matched type. For example, matching `x ≡ y` with `refl` replaces occurrences of `y` with `x` in the current context.
1. The pattern matching function will compute to the body if we send `refl` to this parameter (well, surely you also have to match the other patterns as well).

So, we probably want to port both of these to Cubical type theory. Rewriting the context seems easy, elaborating to `J` (which can be implemented via cubical `transport`) should work, but the computation seems difficult. It seems to me that it is equivalent to regularity, which is known to be difficult to implement (probably impossible -- I just don't want to claim things that I'm not sure. The counterexamples in Carlo Angiuli's thesis seem eternal). So, it's probably impossible from this perspective.

However, in the next iteration of Cubical Agda, there will be support for indexed families, which means the MLTT identity type (which is known to be equivalent to the homogeneous path type) will become available with its full computation rules. Does that mean we can obtain regularity in a cubical type theory with support for indexed families?

Comment: Probably I'm wrong, as MLTT id type is homogeneous. This is a big difference from general path types.

Comment: I don't think having an inductive identity type, or a Swan identity type, with definitional computation on refl and that's equivalent to the path-type, helps at all with making the path-types themselves satisfy regularity.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I think I misused the word 'regularity'. I think in general it's good to have an identity type that computes for `refl`.

Comment: For path-types, I think that is what people call "regularity".

Comment: But that's for path types, right? What we are going to have is about MLTT id type, not path type, so it's not going to help regularity, which means I was wrong

Comment: Right, that was my point.

Comment: What should be done with tag [tag:regularity]? It has no guidance.

Comment: @GuyCoder see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/48947/50892